# I get an org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException from apache png transcoder

Tags: java, svg, png, transcode

I want to generate a png from a svg string with this code:

```
                    try {
                        PNGTranscoder coder = new PNGTranscoder();
                        StringReader reader = new StringReader(getSVG());
                        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(reader);
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("tmp/tmp.png");
                        TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(outputStream);
                        try{
                            coder.transcode(input, transcoderOutput);
                        }finally{
                            reader.close();
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        ErrorHandler.getInstance().handle(e);
                    }
```

But if i run the code, i get an exception because an uri cant be opend because it is corrup or unsupported:

```
org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:0
The URI "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/xxx/xxx.png"
on element <image> can't be opened because:
JDK URL is corrupt or unsupported variant
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter.getBrokenLinkDocument(UserAgentAdapter.java:449)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createRasterImageNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:604)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:327)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.buildImageGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:177)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGImageElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGImageElementBridge.java:119)
[...]
```

While converting this svg: https://hastebin.com/mamudofira.xml

*The image url is replaced for privacy but its working!*

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by first downloading the image as base64 string and then setting it as `xlink:href` in the svg.